Making some Sections .plain and some .insertGrouped in a SwiftUI List
I'm trying to create an image carousel inside a list view in swift that goes to the edge of the screen (no padding like the default list view).
If I set the list view style to .plain, then the HStack for the image carousel will go to the edge of the screen without and border radius in the corners, but it removes the nice section formatting that comes with .insetGrouped. And the .insetGrouped prevents the HStack from reaching the edge of the screen.
I'm trying to find a way to have the nice section formatting and also have the image carousel go the edge.
Here's what I have right now:
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleImage: View {
  var url: String
  var body: some View {
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url)!) { phase in
           switch phase {
           case .empty:
               ProgressView()
               .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
           case .success(let image):
               image
                   .resizable()
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                   .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
                   .clipped()
                   .cornerRadius(10)

           case .failure:
               Image(systemName: "photo")
                   .resizable()
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
                   .foregroundColor(.gray)
           @unknown default:
               EmptyView()
               .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
           }
       }
  }
}

struct AddPhotoView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {}) {
      VStack(spacing: 5) {
        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
          .font(.system(size: 14))
        Text("Add Photo").font(.caption2).bold()
      }.frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 225)
        .background(Color(.systemGray6))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
  }
}

struct ImageGallery: View {
    var body: some View {
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
          ExampleImage(url:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Van-willem-vincent-gogh-die-kartoffelesser-03850.jpg")
          ExampleImage(url :"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Vincent_van_Gogh_-_Head_of_a_skeleton_with_a_burning_cigarette_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg")
          ExampleImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/VanGogh-starry_night_ballance1.jpg")
          AddPhotoView()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
      }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        List {
          
          Section(header: Text("Address")) {
            Text("No Address Specified")
              .foregroundColor(.secondary)
          }
          
          Section {
            NavigationLink {
              EmptyView()
            } label: {
              Label {
                Text("Menu")
                
              } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "menucard")
                  .foregroundColor(.primary)
              }
            }
            NavigationLink {
              EmptyView()
            } label: {
              Label {
                Text("Check-Ins")
              } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "clock.badge.checkmark")
                  .foregroundColor(.primary)
              }
            }
          }
          ImageGallery()
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
        .listSectionSpacing(15)
      }
      // Enable this to have the image carousel expand to the full width of the screen
      // .listStyle(.plain)
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
      .navigationTitle("Place Name")
    }
}

doesn't go to the edge with .insetGrouped

goes to the edges with .plain:


It is indeed unnecessarily difficult to achieve this simple negative indentation of a single section when the List is insetGrouped.
The strange thing is that if it's only .inset, you can add padding, but if it's .insetGrouped you cannot remove horizontal padding as far as the section background goes (as far as I can tell).
So the only way I see to achieve this is by doing exactly that: setting the list to .listStyle(.inset) and then adding back the necessary styles.
To avoid repeating the same styles for every section, I created view extensions. If you wish, you can further add ViewModifier structs for each, but it will work without them.
struct ExampleImage: View {
    var url: String
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url)!) { phase in
            switch phase {
                case .empty:
                    ProgressView()
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
                case .success(let image):
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                case .failure:
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                @unknown default:
                    EmptyView()
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 225)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddPhotoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                Text("Add Photo").font(.caption2).bold()
            }.frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 225)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}

struct ImageGallery: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ExampleImage(url:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Van-willem-vincent-gogh-die-kartoffelesser-03850.jpg")
                ExampleImage(url :"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Vincent_van_Gogh_-_Head_of_a_skeleton_with_a_burning_cigarette_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg")
                ExampleImage(url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/VanGogh-starry_night_ballance1.jpg")
                AddPhotoView()
            }
            // .padding(.horizontal, 12)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func listRowPadding() -> some View {
        self
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
    
    func listSectionPadding() -> some View {
        self
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Address")) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("No Address Specified")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                    .listRowPadding()
                }
                .listSectionPadding()
                
                Section("Links") {
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            EmptyView()
                        } label: {
                            Label {
                                Text("Menu")
                                
                            } icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "menucard")
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.leading, 40)
                            .padding(.trailing, -20)
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            EmptyView()
                        } label: {
                            Label {
                                Text("Check-Ins")
                            } icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "clock.badge.checkmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10) // inner VStack padding
                    .listRowPadding()
                }
                .listSectionPadding()
                
                Section("Gallery") {
                    ImageGallery()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground), in: Rectangle()) // to clear the background
                        .padding(.horizontal, -40)
                        .listRowPadding()
                }
                .listSectionPadding()

            }
            .listStyle(.inset)
            // .padding(.horizontal, -20)
            .listSectionSpacing(0)
        
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("Place Name")
    }
}

This is not a perfect solution, because it still requires to tweak vertical spacing if a section doesn't have a title, but it will mostly achieve the layout you were after.
If a section title for the gallery is not needed, just remove it from a section and add a top padding to the gallery. Or, keep the section and set the title to an empty string ("") and add some negative top padding to the gallery.

